Can I connect a discharged/dead battery directly to a good one?
I had a dry-cell 710 CCA battery on my car and it was working fine. One day the alternator started smoking and the battery light turned on. I shut off the car and checked the battery with a multi meter and I remember it was like 10.5 or 9.5 Then I jump started the car again and saw the alternator doesn't charge the battery at all.
So I bought a new alternator and battery and replaced the alternator and started the car with new battery, no problem.
Now I tested my old battery again and it shows 0 V. I took it to AutoZone and Oreily and both said the battery is dead!
But I think it's only completely discharged and maybe I can recharge it again and it would work again. But as long as I don't have a battery charger, I am wondering if I can connect it directly to a good battery and this way the good battery may charge the old one?
Is that possible?

NOTE: I take it by "dry-cell" you are saying it's an AGM ... at least that's the premise I'm going with.
Yes, there'd be no issue with you putting your "dead" battery in parallel with your other battery. Just make sure you've actually got it parallel when attaching (ie: positive to positive; negative to negative). Chargers can have a hard time telling there is a 12v battery attached to it with an AGM when the voltage gets low.
With that said, I'll have to say, for the multimeter to state the battery shows "0 volts", that thing is most likely completely dead beyond reclamation. Doesn't mean you can't try, just means don't expect too much.
Another thing is, your vehicle's alternator was not designed to recharge a dead battery. It's just there to replace what was used during startup as well as provide replacement juice for what the vehicle uses.
